# Update the data for an existing bubble chart in powerpoint

Tags: python-pptx

If i have a Bubble chart and want to change the chart data with values for x and values for y and values for the bubble size and all of this is indexed with names how to do it.
With the question you will find the data i want to update from the chart.

This is the code i use to change the data inside the chart itself
[Code to change the chart data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2kzS.png)

This is the data i read to add in the chart in the same way with the same index with x values in A column and y values in B column and size values in size column
[data want to replace the chart data with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNUFB.png)

but that what i got from the code the x values become the index and y values are named as the series and the size is right, so how to change the index value for each point and have 2 series x and y and they got a common column named size holding the data of the size?
[the output from code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJUqW.png)

This is the shape of the output graph i want to have[the output graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqOCU.png)     [the data inside the output graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3reVp.png)

Comment: State the conclusions your research so far have led you to believe is the right way, show the code you are using that is not working, and clearly state the errors it is giving you. The documentation for charts in `python-pptx` is here: https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/charts.html. Look for the `chart.replace_data()` method.

Comment: i update the question and added 3 new pictures for the code ,the right data, the output data from the code.

Comment: Have you tried adding a separate series for each (x, y) pair? Is that what you're looking for? Like each bubble has its own color and name? I'm not clear what you're trying to accomplish. Maybe create an example and add a screenshot.

Comment: I added 2 additional photos representing the output graph i want to have and the data related to it.

Comment: How to add pair (x,y) because when i try to do so with add point it gives me error that add point method can't have a tuple in place of y variable.